# Good resolution for a Banner 4x10

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I worked a file to be printed on a 4 x 10 feet banner.
I set up the file size to 48 inches x 120 inches, at 300PPI.

My file was really large (7g), and it was smooth, no apparent pixel when zoomed to print size. Although, when I received the banner, it was ugly and we can see all pixels and the printer said we were bad graphic designers. Can somebody explain if I really did something wrong?

I don't think it should have been printed with a that bad resolution looks.

Comment: Hi Anna-Maria, welcome to GDSE, there's already an answer here for large banners resolution. Try to verify if this answer offers some solution to your resolution and printing issues.

Comment: but I would like to know if what I did was suppose to be okay? if it is my mistake, I don't want to do it again, and if it is the printer fault I would like to be sure.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your file has the four points described at the end of the valid answer and the right resolution?

Comment: No .  but it was saved in TIFF 300PPI 48X120inches and it was a 6.75 GB file.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing both, the source file and the printed result it is hard to tell, but I think you actually did some rookie mistakes. I am commenting those because those are the ones you can work with.

You do not send a 7Gb file to be printed... ever.

No one will work on that file seriously unless you are working in a really closed controlled environment, probably doing something for a Hollywood Blockbuster.

48x120 at 300 PPI is a file of 14,400 x 36,000 px or 518 Megapixels.

Considering that a really high-end camera has around 100Mpx, and a normal camera has 24Mpx...

An image of about 9 times smaller, 48x120 at 100ppi would work better.

---

Why is this important? because the person doing the job just resampled the humongous file to whatever he felt right. And somehow this is normal.

Are you a bad designer? I don't know about the design, but the file was prepared and sent in a wrong way. Again, that is a rookie mistake.

---

Sayed that, the print company personnel are just plain incompetent for two reasons.

1. If the file is not sent in a proper way by the client, they just need to inform you so you correct it.
2. If the file has enough information which it seems in this case, they just need to resample the file, for example reducing the file to 100ppi. No big deal there. But I still think point 1 is the proper way to act.

Comment: Thank you , this is great. So, to make sure I understand,  if I had sent him a 48x120 at 100PPI , it would have been nice and without pixels?  or it is better to smaller the size in inches and keep the 300PPI ?

Comment: Both options are correct. The final result is the same as long as you talk with the provider (and they talk to you) Take a look at the link Danielillo posted as a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will read that carefully